# Script to delete user accounts from Profile list on Windows 8.1

Tags: vbscript, registry, windows-8.1

The following code is meant to delete all user accounts from  **HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList**

Code:

```
On Error Resume Next

Const HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE = &H80000002

strComputer = "."

Set objRegistry=GetObject("winmgmts:\\" & _ 
    strComputer & "\root\default:StdRegProv")

strKeyPath = "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"
objRegistry.EnumKey HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strKeyPath, arrSubkeys

For Each objSubkey In arrSubkeys
    strValueName = "ProfileImagePath"
    strSubPath = strKeyPath & "\" & objSubkey
    objRegistry.GetExpandedStringValue HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE,strSubPath,strValueName,strValue
    strPath=Left(strvalue,Len(strvalue)-Len(Right(strvalue,Len(strvalue)-9)))   
    strID=Right(strvalue,Len(strvalue)-9)
    if ((strPath="C:\Users\") and (strID<>"rcadmin")) then 
    return=objRegistry.DeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strSubPath)
     end if
Next
wscript.echo "Done"
```

If I replace "`return=objRegistry.DeleteKey(HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE, strSubPath)`" with "`wscript.echo strID`", it displays what I expect. So all I need to do now is delete the string "*strSubPath*" from "*HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE*". And this is the part that I can not get right.

An example of the output of

`wscript.echo strSubPath" is "SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows NT\CurrentVersion\ProfileList"\S-1-5-21-3469983464-63224933-1422604425-8029`

What am I missing?

Comment: You are using `On Error Resume Next` so since you didn't explicitly say it my question is: Are you running this with elevated rights. Perhaps take out the `On error` line

Comment: why are you using "return" ? isn't that a reserved word?

Comment: @Damien, He is using that since he is, in theory, capturing the output of the method which is possible. http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa389869(v=vs.85).aspx More than likely he code-bit it from a website that was using it. It should fail since it is not declared.

Comment: @Matt, Basically I have tacked together bits of code I found on the internet. I tried removing the `On error` bit, changed `return` to `x` and ran as administrator. Except for the delete, the code does what it should do. If I replace the `return` line with `wscript.echo strSubPath` it echos the correct text. It's the actual delete that I can't seem to manage.

Comment: You did verify that is the "CORRECT" Registry path? Also, are you sure the account you are using has the rights to delete that key?

Comment: @Damien, yes everything is correct (well not everything :-) ), that paths that is,  and I am running it as a full admin.

Comment: A full admin may not necessarily have enough permissions to remove a registry key... go check the permissions on that registry key... and confirm